# How to set both Navigationbar and statusbar Light theme

Tags: android, material-design

[image]When I set light Navigationbar programmatically the icons of Statusbar goes white. So how to set Navigationbar and Statusbar both light?

Comment: Bit unclear about *Statusbar goes white.* could you please update question with screen-shot?

Comment: @RumitPatel Please check above screenshot. Here status bar icons go white. So not able to see it.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of you probably using  `colorPrimaryDark` as white color in `colors.xml`

```
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</color>
```

So icons are there but we can't see because of same color of icons and statusbar color. To resolve this you'll need to add below line in your theme(`styles.xml`).

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Comment: what is **values.xml?** it should be set in `styles.xml` file in your theme.

Comment: @AkashRatanpara confirm is **values.xml?** there should not be any file like this. this should be directory.